# Clear extra Sitecore SXA html tags from the site pages

Tags: sxa, visual-studio, html

I have `SXA` site pages and I need to clear the extra `Sitecore` `html` tags (script,link).

[image]

After div tag
[image]

Specification:
`Sitecore SXA 10.2`

Can anyone provide any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you do anything, first find out why you have duplicated `</body>`, `</html>` tags. Looks suspicious.

---

Manipulate HTML once tags are rendered by modifying/creating your own version of

`\Views\SxaLayout\SxaLayout.cshtml`

btw.
some SXA `<script>` elements are rendered before `</body>` and that's expected.

Comment: The duplicate tags  are the ones which I have added in the page.